# ipelets folder in ubunut 20.04 for ipe

Tags: software-installation, home-directory

I switched to `Ubuntu 20.04` recently. Now I installed `ipe extensible drawing editor` to draw diagrams in SVG format. I also found an ipelets called [ipeplots](http://webp.svsu.edu/%7Ejhlavace/ipeplots/manual.pdf) to draw the graph of a function in `ipe`. For the installation process, it is given that

> On Unix and Unix-like systems, you can use for example the $HOME/.ipe/ipeletsdirectory.

I don't know how to find the particular folder and hence unable to install the ipeplots. It will be a great help if someone will tell me how to do so.

I have an ipe folded in `Home/snap/ipe` but nothing is there.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?

Comment: Sorry, for that. I included that.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the path by going to IPE editor, help-->show configuration. They should show you the path to the ipelets. For my case it is /usr/lib/ipe/7.2.13/ipelets/.